# Validating Answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in the process of validating answers for a game app I'm building. I am having trouble with the correct database calling.

Question#validate_answer

```
def validate_answer
  @answer = Answer.where(correct: true)
  @correct_answer = @answer
  @selected_answer = params[:answer]

  #check if the submitted answer is the correct answer

  if @selected_answer == @correct_answer
    render :success
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :answers

  has_one :video_clue
  has_many :answers

  def correct_answer
    answers.find_by correct: true 
  end
end
```

Answer.haml

```
 %form#form{:action => results_path(@question), :method => "post"}

- @answers.each do |answer| 

.form-group
.radio

%input{:name => 'q_id', :type => 'hidden',:value =>'#{@question.id}'}

%input.btn.btn-default.btn-block{:name => 'answer', :style => 'vertical-align: middle; margin:0px;', :type => 'submit', :value => answer.text}
```

Seeds.rb

```
q = Question.create question: "In what year did MTV (Music Television) premiere and what was the first music video the channel aired?", category_id: 1
q.answers.create text: '1982 Michael Jackson Bille Jean'
q.answers.create text: '1984 Madonna Like a virgin' 
q.answers.create text: '1981 The Buggles Video Killed The Radio Star', correct: true
```

The goal is to match the selected answer to the correct answer. It keeps rendering the 'fail' page.

Comment: Can you get question in answer? You have to determine you question first in `validate_answer`. If you can get the question, you can change your `@answer = @question.correct_answer` in `def validate_answer`

Comment: I tried that already and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are comparing a string to an ActiveRecord object which of course is going to fail.

i.e. `'1982 Michael Jackson Bille Jean' != <Answer id:1 text:"1982 Michael Jackson Bille Jean">`

Have you considered passing in the answer's id instead of the text and then compare. This will allow you to query for the answer that the user has selected. For example

Question#validate_answer

```
def validate_answer
  @answer = Answer.where(correct: true)
  @correct_answer = @answer
  @selected_answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])

#check if the submitted answer is the correct answer

  if @selected_answer == @correct_answer
    render :success
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```

Or you need to compare the `params[:answer`] to the text attribute

Question#validate_answer

```
def validate_answer
  @answer = Answer.where(correct: true)
  @correct_answer = @answer.text
  @selected_answer = params[:answer]

#check if the submitted answer is the correct answer

  if @selected_answer == @correct_answer
    render :success
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```

Comment: No luck. I don't have params of answer_id. When the user selects an answer, it's suppose to be recognized so that's why I used params[:answer].

Comment: Not sure I understand where you are coming from but I updated with an alternate. you can always pull the text value from the answer. But if you do Answer.where(correct: true) will that not pull all correct answers regardless of the question?

Comment: It does but unfortunately when I do @answer.text I get an error but @answer[0].text will work for the first one.

Comment: You are getting that error because it is returning an ActiveRecord::Relation object which is an array. Assuming you only have one correct answer you can always do `Answer.where(correct: true).first`

Comment: It will work on the first question. For all other questions it will render :error.

Comment: I have updated @pyRabbit Question#validate_answer of the last option. I have added `@answer = Answer.where(correct: true).map(&:text)` and changed the condition `if @correct_answer.include? (@selected_answer)`. I hope this can help.